# What is the probability that he goes to the gymnasium on $5$ days out of $7$ consecutive days of a specified week?

Tags: probability

On any day, Raman is twice as likely to go to gymnasium as he is likely to go for volleyball practice. Given that Raman necessarily goes for exactly one of the two activities each day, what is the probability that he goes to the gymnasium on $5$ days out of $7$ consecutive days of a specified week?

I have a small doubt.
According to me, the probability for going to the gymnasium is $1$, and the 
probability for going to volleyball is $\frac{1}{2}$.

But in the solution it has been given that the probability for going to the gymnasium  is $\frac{2}{3}$ and the probability for playing volleyball is $\frac{1}{3}$.

How?

Comment: Your numbers don't make sense.  The probabilities must add to $1$.

Comment: Try this: Two teams play 7 games against each other. There cannot be any ties. Each game has a winner. In each game team A is twice as likely to win as team B. What is the chance that team A wins exactly 5 games?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the probabilities in a sample space must equal $1$.  Since there are only two possible outcomes, the sum of the probabilities that he attends volleyball practice and that he goes to the gymnasium on any given day must equal $1$.  Let $p$ be the probability that Raman attends volleyball practice.  Since he is twice as likely to go to the gymnasium, the probability that he goes to the gymnasium is $2p$.  Hence,
$$p + 2p = 1$$
Solving for $p$ yields the probability that Raman attends volleyball practice.  You can then find the probability that he goes to the gymnasium by calculating $2p$.